# System.NotSupportedException Cannot store type: Library.Models.UserModel

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm writing uwp program with SQLite DB. The program uses a universal windows library that hold a static class which control the DB. In the exception Stack Trace  i see all the methods of the sqlite, even though it dont get to the break points i put in the DB Manager class.

The model on which the db build on:

```
public class UserModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Connected { get; set; }
}
```

The static db manager:

```
public static class UsersManager
{
    public static event EventHandler NewConnectionHandler=delegate { };

    private static string _path;
    private static SQLiteConnection _conn;

    static UsersManager()
    {
        _path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "usersdb.sqlite");
        _conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), _path);
        _conn.CreateTable<UserModel>();
    }

    private static void OnNewConnection()
    {
        NewConnectionHandler.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public static void Add(UserModel user)
    {
        _conn.Insert(user);
    }

    public static void Delete(int userId)
    {
         _conn.Delete<UserModel>(userId);

    }

    public static bool Contains(string name)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        var user = _conn.Find<UserModel>(u => u.Name == name);

        if (user != null)
            flag = true;

        return flag;
    }

    public static void ConnectUser(UserModel connectedUser,HubConnection hubConnection ,IHubProxy hubProxy)
    {
        _conn.Find<UserModel>(connectedUser).Connected = true;
        _conn.Update(connectedUser);
        var queryStringData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        queryStringData.Add("username", connectedUser.Name);

        hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://127.0.0.1:8080", queryStringData);
        hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
        if (hubConnection.State != ConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            hubConnection.Start();
        }

        OnNewConnection();

    }

    public static ObservableCollection<UserModel> ConnectedUsers
    {
        get
        {
            var allUsers = _conn.Table<UserModel>();
            ObservableCollection<UserModel> disconnectedUsers = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>();
            ObservableCollection<UserModel> connectedUsers = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>();
            foreach (var user in allUsers)
            {
                if (user.Connected)
                    connectedUsers.Add(user);
            }

            return connectedUsers;
        }

    }

    public static ObservableCollection<UserModel> DisconnectedUsers
    {
        get
        {
            var allUsers = _conn.Table<UserModel>(); 
            ObservableCollection<UserModel> disconnectedUsers = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>();
            foreach (var user in allUsers)
            {
                if (!user.Connected)
                    disconnectedUsers.Add(user);
            }

            return disconnectedUsers;
        }

    }
}
```

where the exception occurs:

```
private void SignIn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (userViewModel.SignIn()) //here right after trying execute SignIn() 
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(ContactsView), userViewModel);
        }
    }
```

The SignIn method in the UserViewModel:

```
public bool SignIn()
    {
        bool flag = false;
        if (Name == null || Password == null)
        {
            Error = "Name or password wasnt filled";
        }
        else if (UsersManager.Contains(Name) && !UserSettings.IsNameExict(Name))
        {
            Error = "Name already in use choose diffrent one";
        }
        else
        {
            UserModel user = new UserModel
            {
                Name = Name,
                Password = Password,
            };

            if (!UsersManager.Contains(Name))
            {
                UsersManager.Add(user);
                UserSettings.SaveUserName(Name);
            }

            UsersManager.ConnectUser(user,_hubConnection, _hubProxy);

            flag = true;
        }

        return flag;
    }
```

Hope you guys help me i really tried to find the answer for this. Thank you

**Edit 1:**

Run the program again today and it seems that: the program throws the exception in the UsersManager class in this method:

```
public static void ConnectUser(UserModel connectedUser,HubConnection hubConnection ,IHubProxy hubProxy)
    {


        _conn.Find<UserModel>(connectedUser).Connected = true;//In this line!!!



        _conn.Update(connectedUser);
        var queryStringData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        queryStringData.Add("username", connectedUser.Name);

        hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://127.0.0.1:8080", queryStringData);
        hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
        if (hubConnection.State != ConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            hubConnection.Start();
        }

        OnNewConnection();

    }
```

Comment: What is the error, what does `UserModels` look like? Likely you will need to simplify your code to post the repro, and doing that might solve the problem for you.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT the error specified in the title of this post: System.NotSupportedException Cannot store type: Library.Models.UserModel. The UserModel look like how i put it here under the first code section. And the code is simple MVVM i post it all. Matter of fact, the code is running when i use a collection of UserModel instead of sqlite. So, I dont think that simplifying  the code would solve the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was sending UserModel instance to the `SQLiteConnection.Find<>` method.

The find method works with the pk of the table, so

**Wrong:**

```
_conn.Find<UserModel>(connectedUser);
```

**Right:**

```
_conn.Find<UserModel>(connectedUser.Id);
```

Also it can get lambda expression based on any other property of the model:

```
_conn.Find<UserModel>(u=>u.Name == connectedUser.Name);
```